While running Feature Extraction for VIT model, I am getting Resource Exhausted Error
While running Feature Extraction for VIT model for 2000 images, I am getting Resource Exhausted Error. We are using Google Colab Pro plan. We selected Compute Machine as T4 GPU.
We find that GPU RAM is getting exhausted - 13.5 GB out of 15 GB full (showing RED indicator)
However System RAM of 51 GB is unutilised. (see image).
def extract_features(model, data):
    outputs = model(data)
    return outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0, :].numpy()

features_train = extract_features(vit_model, X_train_vit)
features_test = extract_features(vit_model, X_test_vit)

We expect that both the available RAMs are to be used.  Although we are on a paid plan, the System RAM of 51 GB does not seem to be getting utilised, while the GPU RAM of 15 GB is getting exhausted, during the Feature Extraction Process.
When, we tried with images of 100 each, then there is no error (see below)
def extract_features(model, data):
    outputs = model(data)
    return outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0, :].numpy()

features_train = extract_features(vit_model, X_train_vit[0:100])
features_test = extract_features(vit_model, X_test_vit[0:100])

But, how do we aggregate the features if we choose to do sequentially with 100 images at a time ?    Please guide
